# Adding Children in the second column of QTreeWidget using C++

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I am making one simple program of in which i have two arrays. I want to insert first array in the first column of the child of treeWidget and second array in the second column of the treeWidget. First array is inserted successfully. Now i want to insert second array in the same index of second column. Like this

```
object
   //First Column                          //Second Column
     A                                          1
     B                                          2
     C                                          3
```

Object is the parent.
Coding:

```
QTreeWidget* item= new QTreeWidgetItem();
QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> items_first_Column;
QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> items_Second_Column;

item->setText(0,"Object");
item->addChildren(items_first_column);
```

Can anyone please tell me how i can insert second column in this.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to restructure your code a little bit I think. The second column does not consist of a new bunch of `QTreeWidgetItems`. There is only on list of child items, but instead each item can contain text in several colums.

So you'll have to create a single list of items and put you data into these with [QTreeWidgetItem::setText()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#setText) for example, giving the column number as the first parameter.

You could iterate over both your lists and change the items of `items_first_Column` to contain the text of those from `items_Second_Column` in their second column. But if possible I would advise to restructure your surrounding code to take this into account beforehand.